# Custom query on sequelize seeder

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, postgresql-9.4, sequelize-cli

Any one know how to custom select query on sequelize seeder

I have tried two ways, but no one work

**First attempt**

```
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query(
      'SELECT * FROM "Users" WHERE username = "admin"',
      { type: queryInterface.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }
    ).then(function(users) {});
    },
```

and then got error

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: column "admin" does not exist
```

I do not understand why admin is column here ???

**Second attempt**

```
return queryInterface.sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM "Users" WHERE username = :admin', {
  replacement: {
    admin: 'admin'
  },
  type: queryInterface.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
}).then(function(users) {
});
```

Below error occurred

`SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near ":"`

**Third attempt**

```
return queryInterface.sequelize.query(
  'SELECT * FROM "Users" WHERE username = ' admin '',
  {type: queryInterface.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
.then(function(users) { })
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

**UPDATED**

**Fourth attempt**

```
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query(
      'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = "admin"',
      { type: queryInterface.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }
    ).then(function(users) {});
```

Another error appear:

```
    SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "Users" does not exist
```

**`queryInterface.sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM "Users"')` works without any error. I think the problem here is WHERE querying**

It's driving me to crazy :)

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: In the first attempt, you should remove the quote around users

Comment: It does not work. See my updated Shivam :)

Comment: Don't use double quotes in a query unless you want to create/use an identifier. Your query should be written: `"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = 'admin'"`

Comment: @JorgeCampos Sorry. but an error as same as third attempt.

Comment: @ToanTran Regarding your fourth attempt. Have you tried putting `Users` in quotes in the SQL statement?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it but `SequelizeDatabaseError: column "admin" does not exist`. Anyway, I have founded the solution when I read docs carefully. Let's me update the answer :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have found solution for this issue after reading Sequelize document carefully. [Sequelize raw queries replacements](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html#replacements). If you face the same issue, please try following solution

```
return queryInterface.sequelize.query(
  'SELECT * FROM "Users" WHERE username = ? ', {
    replacements: ['admin'],
    type: queryInterface.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
  }).then(users => {
```

Comment: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/raw-queries/#replacements updated link

Answer (score 0):

In relation to @Toan Tran answer, to update your migration:

```
await queryInterface.sequelize.query(`
      UPDATE public."Table"
      SET "column_to_be_updated" = :column::uuid
      WHERE public."Permissions"."column_to_check" = :column_to_check
    `, {
        replacements: { column_to_be_updated: r.uuid, column_to_check: r.name },
        type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE
      });
```

This is for Sequelize, using PostgresSQL. Note that this update also is for the `column` with type `Sequelize.UUID`.